# Silence alarm via IPMI

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

I have an old Intel SC5400 based server with an Intel S5000PSL board with redundant power running CentOS 6. One of the power supplies has failed and I would like to silence the alarm temporarily.

Is there a way to silence the alarm via IPMI or similar?

`ipmi-sensors -r 24` kindly tells me the problem, but I don't see anything in the ipmitool suite to silence the alarm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question from 2014 is too old to answer and is likely not relevant any more.

Answer (score 1):

OpenIPMI's ipmitool does not support the proprietary Intel extensions to IPMI that might provide this feature. You might have better luck with ipmiutil which seems to support disabling alarms through Intel's IMB driver or maybe through OpenIPMI's /dev/ipmi0:

```
http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/man.htm#ialarms
```